Discord Python Bot not working. Gives error AttributeError: 'Select' object has no attribute 'user'
Here is a code snippet of the class.
from discord import ButtonStyle, SelectOption, Embed
from discord.ui import Button, View
import discord

# Import the necessary functions from akashasql.py

from akashasql import getchocobits, addchocobits
class StoreView(View):
def __init__(self):
super().__init__()
self.selected_item = None

    async def fetch_user_chocobits(self, user_id):
        # Fetch user's chocobits from the database
        return getchocobits(user_id)
    
    @discord.ui.select(
        placeholder="Choose an item to buy...",
        options=[
            SelectOption(label="Test1", description="Costs 100 chocobits", value="100"),
            SelectOption(label="Test2", description="Costs 200 chocobits", value="200"),
        ],
    )
    async def select_callback(self, select, interaction):
        user_id = interaction.user.id
        user_chocobits = await self.fetch_user_chocobits(user_id)
        self.selected_item = select.values[0]
        price = int(self.selected_item)
        if user_chocobits < price:
            await interaction.response.send_message("You do not have enough chocobits.", ephemeral=True)
            self.stop()
        else:
            # Clear the select menu before adding a new item
            self.clear_items()
            self.add_item(Button(label="Confirm Buy", style=ButtonStyle.green))
            # Update the message with the new view
            await interaction.response.edit_message(content=f"Selected item costs {price} chocobits. Confirm purchase?", view=self)
    
    @discord.ui.button(label="Confirm Buy", style=ButtonStyle.green)
    async def confirm_callback(self, button, interaction):
        user_id = interaction.user.id
        price = int(self.selected_item)
        addchocobits(user_id, -price)  # Deduct the price from user's chocobits
        user_chocobits = await self.fetch_user_chocobits(user_id) - price
        await interaction.response.send_message(f"Purchase confirmed! You now have {user_chocobits} chocobits left.", ephemeral=True)
        self.stop()

This is meant to put a embed in the discord server where uses can use "ChocoBis" to buy various items (test1 and test2). However when I select a item to buy, it gives me this error:
    user_id = interaction.user.id
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Select' object has no attribute 'user'

I have no clue whats going on
I expected it to go to the next screen, but unfortunately the bot is "Not responding" and the error message is still here.
This is my first time on stack exchange so sorry for the poor formatting

Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please take the time to format your code properly and include the full traceback error.

Out of curiosity, what version of Discord.py are you using?

I don't know about discord, but looking at the callbacks,  I see two different types of definitions for the callback.  One that has the select and interaction parameter,  and the other with just the interaction parameter.

The error is clear -- the interaction object does not have a .user attribute.  So, why did you expect it to?  Did you write this code yourself from scratch, or did you follow some example?

You have to distinguish between discord classes Interaction and InteractionResponse. The select_callback function passes an InteractionResponse.

Thank you so much for the help. Have sorted it out with your assistance
